# How to create volume stream control in Android

Tags: java, android, andengine, audio

I am an android application developers using AndEngine. I have a problem to make a seek bar to control volume of a sound. how to make the seek bar when the application is running?

Comment: Hoping my post may help you

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented seekbar in this way:

```
public void updateTimerProgress(float width) { 
        if( progressBar != null){
            progressBar.detachSelf();
        }


        progressBar = new Sprite(-0.2f, 0, Utility.getTexRegFromTexPack(ShooterTexPack.YELLOWBAR_ID, activity.shooterTexPack) , activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        progressBar.setWidth(width);
        emptyProgressBarBg.attachChild(progressBar);
    }
```

i am updating based on my time interval.